# SQL statement adding a wildcard to expand the results

Tags: sql, wildcard

So here is the portion of my statement in question:

```
sql = "(rm.dv_id LIKE '${user.employee.organization.divisionId}')">
```

I am trying to adjust this restriction to expand the record results. When I run this restriction against a user with a `dv_id=ENV/BPOS` the results return only showing rm records that are the same `dv_id`. I would like to expand the expression so that it will return rm records like ENV% (for example ENV/BPOS and also ENV/CPD). Is there a way to somehow add a wildcard?

I was told that I need to parse the statement to include "%". I have tried adding this to the end of the string and it results in an error.

Comment: And what is the error? Where exactly did you put the `%`?

Comment: Please give some examples of inputs which match, match and should not, match not but should, ....

Comment: Tag your question with your DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, etc)

Comment: Show the change for "adding this to the end ".

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a guess but did you add the % to the end of the string like this:

```
'ENV'%
```

It has to be part of the string like this:

```
'ENV%'
```

Comment: I would like it to call the dv-Id of the employee, which could be ENV% or CHS%, etc. This is why I need to wildcard the DivisionID in the string

Comment: @AmandaF Can you edit your question to show where it is currently failing with %?

Comment: I am not sure where I put the % in the string:                                              sql = "(rm.dv_id LIKE '${user.employee.organization.divisionId}')">

Comment: Look at my example, the % should go inside the single quotes.

Comment: But wont this only work for em.dv_id like ENV? What about other scenarios like em.dv_id like CHS?                                                          sql = "(rm.dv_id LIKE '${user.employee.organization.divisionId}')">. I would like the script to call the em.dv_id (for example em.dv_id = ENV/BPOS) and use the result to search the rm.dv_id records that are like (for example rm.dv_id = ENV/BPOS, ENV/CPD, etc) So where do I add the %?

Comment: What is divisionId - is it ENV, CHS, etc?

Comment: examples include: ENV/BPOS, ENV/CPD, CHS/PH, CHS/PSS

Comment: Then you want to take a substring of the id then add the %.